# Impact of Deleting Azure AD DS

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

In my organization, we have Azure active directory with all employee details and we don't have on-premises AD. I need to deploy Azure Active Directory Domain Services (Azure AD DS) to work on some integration with our product. So this domain service would be used by only me and one other team member.
I have below queries, can someone clarify:

i)  Will deploying Azure AD DS affect information stored in Azure Active Directory?

> Deploying Azure AD DS service should not disrupt other users usage of Azure services. So would like to know, will deploying this service affect Azure Active Directory or other Azure Services?

ii) What will be the impact if i delete Azure AD Domain Services?

> After my usage, i would be deleting this service, as it is not required anymore. Again would like to know, will it affect any azure services or data stored in Azure Active Directory?

Sorry if it is so vague. I am new to Azure world, so forgive me if it is unclear or wrong. Please help me out.

Creating a trial account and then trying integration is not an option for me. So please avoid suggesting me this.  Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Deploying Azure AD DS won't affect any information stored in Azure Active Directory. Deleting AAD DS won't adversely impact Azure Active Directory.

Kindly go through this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/delete-aadds) and get more information about Deleting AAD DS. I recommend you to kindly check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/faqs) get more information about AAD DS.

If you have any further queries kindly let me know .

Comment: Thanks @Thirgiftthub - MSFT Identity for answering my query.  
In below link, that you shared:  
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/delete-aadds    What does custom OU mean? Is it same as normal Organizational Unit?

Comment: i have read somewhere that ADD DS is read-only. We can't create any entity in domain services. How can i create new users or groups in managed domain alone, so that my data in Azure AD is not disturbed?  
  Can i create users or groups in Azure AD Domain Services alone?

Comment: @LoneWolf regarding the Custom OU in Azure active Directory Domain services kindly check this link to get a detailed information - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/create-ou

Comment: Regarding creating user - you can create a user account in managed Domain and it doesn't available in Azure AD.  But mostly they will use for creating a service accounts. Kindly check this document - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/administration-concepts